# check if scrollbar is visible with virtual dom

Tags: reactjs

So I was reading the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible

This is what I am going with...

```
function hasScrollbar() {
    console.log(
        "hasScrollbar:",
        document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight
    );
    return document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
}
```

```
<div
    className="landing-top"
    style={{ paddingRight: hasScrollbar() ? "0px" : `${scrollBarWidth}px` }}
></div>
```

However, because of reacts virtual dom, it doesn't seem to be reading it correctly...

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `document.body.clientHeight > window.innerHeight`

Comment: @AliYaghoubi it still reads as false.

Comment: Are you sure you want to scroll through the body? I checked this on several different websites and get the true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason this didn't work when I tried it before, but it is working now...

```
const [isScrollBarVisible, setIsScrollBarVisible] = useState(false);
```

```
function hasScrollbar() {
  return document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsScrollBarVisible(hasScrollbar());
}, [isLoadingData, isSearchingData, searchText]);
```

```
<div
  className="landing-top"
  style={{ paddingRight: isScrollBarVisible ? '0px' : `${scrollBarWidth}px` }}
>...more html elements here...</div>
```

I think all I ended up doing to fix it was restarting the server. Very weird, but this is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

const overflows = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. I even tried using useEffect with a timeout.